# Вывести часть слова s после первого символа a длиной n

Tags: python, python-3.x

Пользователь вводит строку `s`, символ `a` и число `n`.
Вывести: часть слова `s` после первого символа `a` длиной `n`.

Результат вывести в верхнем регистре. Если такого нет, вывести `---`
Помогите пожалуйста исправить код

```
s = input()
a = input()
n = int(input())
for i in range (len (s)):
        if a*n:
             print (upper(s) [a:len(s)])
        else:
             print ("---")
```

Comment: Что Вы хотели проверить проверкой `if a*n`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

можно сделать так

```
s=input()
a=input ()
n=int(input())
if a in s: 
    i=s.index(a) #Возвращает индекс первого вхождения
    print((s[i:i+n]).upper()) #Извлекаем срез из строк
else:
    print ("---")
```